# Best practices for static methods and variables with MooTools classes

Tags: javascript, oop, static, mootools

Are there any best practices or common solutions to adding support for "static" methods and variables to MooTools-generated classes?

In particular, is there any solution that ensures that static initialization takes place before the instance `initialize` method is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Caveat: Never used MooTools. I've used Prototype a fair bit, though, which has a similar `Class` system (MooTools is either "inspired by" or a fork of Prototype, depending on who you ask).*

Just add them as properties on the resulting "class":

```
var MyClass = new Class(properties);
MyClass.staticMethod = function() {
    // ...
};
```

(The first line above is from [the docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class); the remainder is my addition.)

You know that will happen prior to `initialize` on any new instance because you're not leaving an opportunity for creating a new instance prior to attaching your static methods (or properties).

Comment: staticMethod is going to be unavailable to instances of MyClass, not sure if this is desired but keep it in mind. you would be able to call `MyClass.staticMethod()` - and for increased readability, use `MyClass.extend({ method: function() ... , method2: function() ...});`

Comment: @Dimitar: `staticMethod` would be available to instances of `MyClass` just as it is to anything else, as `MyClass.staticMethod()`.

Comment: thats exactly the thing, it's not available (from my experience) - http://www.jsfiddle.net/fWQBM/ -> you can call it on MyClass but not on instances. same for .extend - but you can add methods to the instance directly. mootools !=== prototype

Comment: @Dimitar: Right. The OP asked for how to add **static** methods. This does that. If you want instance methods, you define them in the properties you hand to `new Class`.

Comment: I know, just thought I should mention it as it threw me off when I first tried adding new methods to a class defined elsewhere :)

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is old, but I wanted to give a better answer than was already stated.
I recommend the following syntax for static methods:

```
var MyClass = new Class({
    initialize: function() {
        this.method();
        MyClass.staticMethod();
    }
    ,
    method: function() {}
}).extend({
    staticMethod: function() {}
});
```

The `.extend({})` method is the standard way to add static methods on a Class.

The only thing I don't like is the `MyClass.staticMethod();` syntax, but there aren't many better options.

Answer (score 1):

### Appitizer...

Static methods in JavaScript are properties of the Object which references them. They are not added to the prototype of the Object.

There are two ways to add a function to an object in JavaScript. Below, I am adding methods to an imaginary object called, "`MyObject`".

1. Property

   ```
   MyObject.staticMethod = new function() {};

   MyObject.staticMethod(); // Call static method.
   ```
2. Method

   ```
   MyObject.prototype.instanceMethod = new function() {};

   new MyObject().instanceMethod(); // Call instance method.
   ```

### Main Course...

There are three (3) ways to add static methods to a class. The code below is derived from *"Pro JavaScript with MooTools"* by Mark Obcena.

I included some more information which was lacking from Arcabard's answer.

#### 1. As an Object property

```
var Person = new Class({
    // Instance Variables
    name: '',
    age: 0,
    // Constructor
    initialize: function(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    },
    // Instance Methods
    log: function() {
        console.log(this.name + ', ' + this.age);
    }
});

// Static Property
Person.count: 0;
// Static Methods
Person.addPerson: function() {
    this.count += 1;
};
Person.getCount: function() {
    console.log('Person count : ' + this.count);
};
```

#### 2. Using the `extend()`

```
var Person = new Class({
    // Instance Variables
    name: '',
    age: 0,
    // Constructor
    initialize: function(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    },
    // Instance Methods
    log: function() {
        console.log(this.name + ', ' + this.age);
    }
});

Person.extend({
    // Static Property
    count: 0,
    // Static Methods
    addPerson: function() {
        this.count += 1;
    },
    getCount: function() {
        console.log('Person count : ' + this.count);
    }
});
```

#### 3. Adding a new mutator to `Class.Mutators`

```
// This will create a shortcut for `extend()`.
Class.Mutators.Static = function(members) {
    this.extend(members);
};

var Person = new Class({
    Static: {
        // Static Property
        count: 0,
        // Static Method
        addPerson: function() {
            this.count += 1;
        },
        getCount: function() {
            console.log('Person count : ' + this.count);
        }
    },
    // Instance Variables
    name: '',
    age: 0,
    // Constructor
    initialize: function(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    },
    // Instance Methods
    log: function() {
        console.log(this.name + ', ' + this.age);
    }
});
```

Example using the static methods.

```
// Creating a new Person instance
var mark = new Person('Mark', 23);
mark.log();

// Accessing the static method
Person.addPerson();
Person.getCount() // 'Person count: 1'
```

Answer (score -1):

Excerpt from *"Pro Javascript with Mootools"*:

> The extend method is declared via `Function.prototype` and is inherited by all functions. Because a MooTools class is in essence a function, we could use the extend method for classes too. The method is similar to the implement method in that it takes an object argument with keys and values referring to members that will be added. Unlike implement, though, extend does not add the members to the prototype of the class, but to the class object itself.

```
// You can implement a `Static` mutator for creating static methods and variables:
Class.Mutators.Static = function(members) {
    this.extend(members);
}

// Using the Static mutator above
var Person = new Class({
    Static: {
        // Static Property
        count: 0,
        // Static Method
        addPerson: function() {
            this.count += 1;
        },
        getCount: function(){
            console.log('Person count: ' + this.count);
        }
    }
});
```

See [MooTools: `Types > Function > extend()`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Function:extend) for more information.

Comment: -1 The "Static:" mutator you're using here is NOT part of MooTools -- it is actually [sample code from earlier in the book](http://books.google.com/books?id=uI-DOdqB-NoC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=mootools+static+mutator&source=bl&ots=oOGSEVGyad&sig=T4GFLNR_iz--hWdEnMT8bp0hLEU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AmOlUPqkI4z0iwKUm4HgDQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=mootools%20static%20mutator&f=false).  Also, this example doesn't even show how to use `.extend()`.